# assembly-Invalid language element mips

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am trying to execute a very simple program but I keep getting the error :`Invalid language element`

```
lw $t0, 0($a0)               #load integer from $a0->$t0
beq $t0, 1, 1dimensional     #branch if $t0=1

1dimensional:
do something
```

I cant understand why I am getting the error.

Comment: http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html says BEQ takes two register operands and a label, not an immediate.

Comment: @PeterCordes Using an immediate as the second argument is _valid_, because `beq` is a pseudo-op [if the assembler suports it, which `mars` does]. It generates the following "real" instruction sequence: `addi $at,$zero,1` / `beq $at,$t0,1dimensional`.

Comment: Ah, ok, then not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760255/why-we-cant-compare-bne-beq-a-register-with-an-immediate-assembly-mips after all, if you use an assembler which will destroy $r1 for you while expanding beq as a pseudo-op.  That seems really weird to me, but I guess when you have 31 architectural registers, it's "ok" to waste some of them, like the two that the OS is allowed to clobber asynchronously.

Comment: `$1` is the "assembler temporary" (`$at`), which is used by some pseudo-instructions to hold an intermediate result. It's fine to use it as a regular GPR if you avoid pseudo-instructions, or make sure that you don't rely on its value being preserved across any pseudo-instruction usage.

Answer (score 2):

You left out a crucial part of the error message, namely *what* the invalid language element was.
What the assembler is complaining about is the label `1dimensional`. It's common for assemblers to only allow letters and underscores (and possibly a single `.`) as the first character of a label. So change the name of that label to something that meets that requirement, e.g. `onedimensional`.